# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable on laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I just set the code as below and it's show the error. May I know how to fix it?

```
public function productsCat(Request $request){
    $cat_id = $request->cat_id;

    $priceCount = count($request->price);
}
```

Comment: it already says it all in the error message, `$request->price` must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Comment: You should read documentation before asking questions: [PHP count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using PHP 7.2 use @count to suppress this error

Answer (score 0):

You can use the laravel helper (collect):

```
public function productsCat(Request $request){
    $cat_id = $request->cat_id;

    $priceCount = collect($request->price)->count();
}
```